# Intermittent multi-second hang while logging to an SSD... how to debug what's happening?

Tags: c++, disk, ofstream, solid-state-drive

I've got a program that simply writes out to a text file on the disk (on the system drive c:), flushing after every write (to ensure the disk is updated if the program crashes shortly after). I measure the time the write and flush take. Typically it is a millisecond or two at most. But it will occasionally spike to *seconds*, particularly when using the PC for other activity like internet browsing. Here's a sample run:

```
New max of 0.000116 at 0.539845
New max of 0.000213 at 0.543778
New max of 0.000710 at 0.544586
New max of 0.018609 at 0.546615
New max of 0.018748 at 11.417722
New max of 0.043486 at 14.663091
New max of 6.305320 at 21.654646
Hiccup of 6.305320 at 21.654646
```

If I have the program output to a different SSD (non-system), or run on another PC's system drive, I don't see such hiccups. The write-rate of the program is nothing super-demanding (13MB/s). What could be causing such drastic hiccups, and is there a way I can verify the hypothesis? (Event viewer, disk logs somewhere, etc?)

Task manager will show a sudden drop in the disk's active time before it resumes. The disk where the spikes happen is about 90% full, which I know isn't ideal for SSDs. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Windows.h"
class TimeHelper
{
public:
    TimeHelper()
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&m_initialQPC);
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&m_qpf);
    }
    double GetTime()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER currentQPC;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&currentQPC);
        auto difference = currentQPC.QuadPart - m_initialQPC.QuadPart;
        return difference * 1.0 / m_qpf.QuadPart;
    }
private:
    LARGE_INTEGER m_qpf, m_initialQPC;
};
int main()
{
    TimeHelper timeHelper;
    std::ofstream of("c:\\deleteme\\output.txt");
    int64_t i = 0;
    double max = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        auto start = timeHelper.GetTime();
        of << "[" << std::to_string(start) << "] The count is " << std::to_string(i) << std::endl << std::flush;
        auto end = timeHelper.GetTime();
        auto difference = end - start;
        if (difference > max)
        {
            max = difference;
            std::cout << "New max of " << std::to_string(difference) <<" at " << std::to_string(start) << std::endl;
            of << "New max of " << std::to_string(difference) << std::endl << std::flush;
        }
        if (difference > 0.5)
        {
            std::cout << "Hiccup of " << std::to_string(difference) << " at " << std::to_string(start) << std::endl;
            of << "hiccup of " << std::to_string(difference) << std::endl << std::flush;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Anti-virus?  Or perhaps reshuffling in the SSD driver if you are that full, but honestly, these are guesses.

Comment: Maybe the cheapest option is to just buy better hardware (cost of better hardware likely being less than the cost of man-hours needed to find a solution with current hardware). Worth considering at least.

Comment: I've got the antivirus disabled. And nothing is going on at the CPU level of note either. The SSD Is a good one, just full - an 850 PRO 1TB with 85.2GB free. I know performance gets worse as SSDs fill, but a 6 second flush is jaw-dropping. ;-)

Comment: I can avoid the hardware - there are other SSDs in the system - I'd just really like to understand what's going on so that I can prevent it in the future. I've got other programs that write to disk at much higher rates, and understanding whether this is faulty hardware or to be expected would be great.

Comment: @aggieNick02 I think this is *precisely* the kind of performance problem that people complain about with *some* SSDs. Note that the OS would like to make these hiccups happen only when you're not using the SSD, but since you're constantly writing, it can't.

Comment: @user253751 - that makes sense - I'd really like to find the indications of what the OS/driver is doing though. And this happens within a minute or two, so it seems beyond the realm of something like regularly scheduled OS maintenance.

Comment: Windows has a Performance Monitor tool (perfmon) that might help you investigate this, see: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/windows-performance-monitor-overview/ba-p/375481

Comment: @PaulSanders - powershell was a good suggestion, thanks. Caught a nice 3-second hiccup. When it happens, disk idle time falls to 0% and disk queue length shoots up. So it sure looks like the disk has just paused responding. There are no events in event viewer though - I've tried enabling any logs there that have anything to do with disk to no avail.